# how can we use jqTree jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtree

i'm using jqTree plugin. but in console.log it has an error that says:"$(.....).tree " is not a function.
but in the link http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Plugin-for-Tree-Widget-jqTree.html it says just tree function like below.

```
$('#tree').tree({
  data:data,
  autoOpen:true
  });
```

what wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You sure you included jqTree in the page?

Comment: yes for sure. 
 <script src="js/api/tree.jquery.js"></script>
 <link href="css/jqtree.css" rel="stylesheet">
do you try it?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? Since it also might be the data that causes the function to throw and error and stop working(It shouldn't do that but there is always a chance).